# why breakpoints don't work when debugging Silverlight app?

Tags: c#, silverlight, debugging

I debug my Silverlight application and when I put breakpoint in push button even, it don't invoke when I push it. Don't You know why it is ? Why then my app don't pause and I don't move to code to iterate through line of code?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I had the same issue with Firefox. 
Change the default browser: Browse with... > Internet Explorer > Set as default.

And check your web project properties: Start Options > Debuggers: 
ASP.NET and Silverlight should be selected.

That should work.

Comment: +1 My guess... Web project properties > Start Options > Debuggers: Silverlight not checked.

Comment: Also make sure that "ASP.NET" and "Native code" are unchecked.  I've had trouble with multiple options checked

Answer (score 3):

Also check you're in Debug not Release mode.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest thing to do is to make sure you are deploying your app from within Visual Studio (by pressing F5).  If you simply compile your app to a web server and run it from the web server, there's nothing inherently connecting the Visual Studio debugger to the Silverlight application.  In its default setup, pressing F5 will give you debug support in Silverlight applications.

I know there's a way to attach a debugger to windows applications from within Visual Studio without pressing F5, but I'm not sure if you can do that with Silverlight applications running on your Windows machine.